# Show when scrolling up and hide when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the div show when I scrollup and when I scrolldown into the page it will appear.

Help me please Im newbie in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function MyUpDownFunction(){

    var top-height= $('header-div-element').position().top + <any-other-custom-height>;


    if( $(window).scrollTop() > top-height ){
        $('#your-div').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('#your-div').slideUp();
    }
}
```